# jQuery Mobile Checkbox CSS

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, jquery-mobile

I want to style checkboxes on a page with JQuery Mobile, but can't isolate the CSS for the checkboxes. [Here is the complete CSS](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.css), but when I link to that in  it messes up all my formatting. I'd prefer to only include the CSS necessary to style the checkboxes, but can't figure it out using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try global searching the css for checkbox?

I found this but it may not be all you need.

```
/* checks,radios */
.ui-icon-checkbox-off,
.ui-icon-checkbox-on,
.ui-icon-radio-off,
.ui-icon-radio-on {
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
.ui-icon-checkbox-off {
    background-image: url(images/form-check-off.png);
}
.ui-icon-checkbox-on {
    background-image: url(images/form-check-on.png);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just using that isn't enough, the checkboxes still don't appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes use a bunch of margin to do certain effects, you have to see if that is where you are falling. I am facing the same issue right now... probably going to change it by adding my own checkboxes... things are just not compartmentalized enough.